# Supertest/mocha done parameter passed within tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

Below is the code that I wrote with mocha, chai and supertest. I have a question with regards to the segment of code below that works, with focus on token.

```
describe('Authenticated userTest', function () {
    var token;

    before(function loginAuth(done) {
        request(app)
            .post("/login/local")
            .send("username=testName")
            .send("password=qwe123QWE")
            .expect(function (res) {
                should.exist(res.body.token);
                token = res.body.token;
            })
            .end(done);
    });

    it('should give me a defined token', function(done) {
        console.log("token is " + token);
        done();
    });
});
```

Apparently, token is defined all well and good here. However, when I remove the done function as follows:

```
describe('Authenticated userTest', function () {
    var token;

    before(function loginAuth() { //done is removed here
        request(app)
            .post("/login/local")
            .send("username=testName")
            .send("password=qwe123QWE")
            .expect(function (res) {
                should.exist(res.body.token);
                token = res.body.token;
            })
            .end(); //done is removed here
    });

    it('should give me a defined token', function(done) {
        console.log("token is " + token);
        done();
    });
});
```

Token becomes undefined. From what I understand, done is a function passed down from the before hook to all the various tests thereafter that starts with `it(...)` from the inbuilt source code.

Thus, I want to clarify that particular question (if done is passed only across the tests; if done only accepts the err parameter) and why did the token become undefined after removing the done parameter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Token didn't become undefined... at the point you try to use it, it is *still* undefined. `token` has not yet been set because mocha does not know it is working with an async test.

See https://justinbellamy.com/testing-async-code-with-mocha/